# How do I compare the value of two rows in a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas

I was asked to create a new boolean column, where I have to compare whether the price have gone up from the previous day. For instance, the second row of signal should be a True since 193.60 > 178.97.

I tried to iterate the rows and extracting the 'close' value and compare them. However, it doesnt work.

[image: 1]

Comment: Take a look at [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html).

Comment: alright thx man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=0
b=df[0]['Close']
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    a = df[i]['Close']
    if b < a:
        df[i]['Signal'] = True
    else:
        df[i]['signal'] = False

    b=a

print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us do `shift`

```
df['Sig'] = df['Close'].shift().fillna(0)<df['Close']
```